# NETCore 2.1 - Unable to access mssql server / SqlExeption: Cannot open database "DbName" requested by the login. The login failed

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Me and my team are working on a project, which is a NETCore 2.1 MVC web app, in Visual Studio 2017, and this project has a MSSQL Database. I have no problem accessing this db, however, my colleagues are getting the following exception:

> SqlException: Cannot open database "MSSQL_DB" requested by the login. The login failed.
>       Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-machinename\windowsLogin'.

After researching the problem on web I can see that most of the times the issue is with ASP.NET not being configured to use Windows authentication. So in addition I made the following changes, however still the same issue persists.

Added web.config file to project :

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>
    <system.web>
       <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    </system.web>
 </configuration>
```

Modified the appsettings.json by adding Integrated Security=False :

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {    
"DbConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MSSQL_DB;Integrated Security=False;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

launchsetings.json :

```
{
"iisSettings": {
"windowsAuthentication": true,
"anonymousAuthentication": false,
"iisExpress": {
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:43064",
  "sslPort": 44395
}
},
"profiles": {
"IIS Express": {
  "commandName": "IISExpress",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
  },
  "NETCore2IdentityWebApp_v3": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  },
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
}
}
}
```

Also what is maybe worth mentioning, at the end of Configure method, there is a method that checks if there are any user roles added to roles table, and if not, it adds them. Whenever the exception happens, it happens on the line where we execute this method.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider servpro)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseSession();
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "searchresults",
            template: "searchresults",
            defaults: new { controller = "SearchResults", action = "SearchResults" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "hotel",
            template: "hotel",
            defaults: new { controller = "Hotel", action = "Hotel" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "hotels",
            template: "hotels",
            defaults: new { controller = "Hotels", action = "Hotels" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "contact",
            template: "contact",
            defaults: new { controller = "Contact", action = "Contact" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "booking",
            template: "booking",
            defaults: new { controller = "Booking", action = "Booking" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });

    InitRoles.CreateRoles(servpro).Wait(); //Exception happens here
}
```

And the `InitRoles` class:

```
public class InitRoles
{
    public static async Task CreateRoles(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var RoleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        var UserManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        string[] roleNames = { "Admin", "Standard" };
        IdentityResult roleResult;

        foreach (var roleName in roleNames)
        {
            var roleExist = await RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName);
            if (!roleExist)
            {
                //create the roles and seed them to the database: Question 1
                roleResult = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(roleName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if any other info is required.

Comment: `.Wait();` may be causing a deadlock which results in a timeout

Comment: What happens if you just let the async code run without waiting?

Comment: @NKosi, thanks, that seemed to work! Would you suggest to leave the async method without .Wait(), or can this be done with .wait(), but differently?

Comment: If nothing is immediately dependent on the async call completing before its execution then leave it without the wait. You could alternatively do an async event handler when you can await the call and then invoke what is dependent on that code completing first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.Wait();` may be causing a deadlock which results in a timeout.

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

If nothing is immediately dependent on the async call completing before its execution then leave it without the wait.

```
//...

InitRoles.CreateRoles(servpro);
```

You could alternatively do an async event handler where you can await the call and then invoke what is dependent on that code completing first.

```
private event EventHandler creatingRoles = delegate { };

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider servpro) {

    //...omitted for brevity

    EventHandler handler = null;

    handler = async (sender, args) => {
        creatingRoles -= handler; //unsubscribe from event

        await InitRoles.CreateRoles(servpro);

        //...code dependent on the above completing

        //...
    };
    creatingRoles += handler; //subscribe to event
    creatingRoles(this, EventArgs.Empty); //raise event
}
```